# exclude Test.java class from maven build war

Tags: maven

I've tried to exclude some .java file of src/test/java from being packaged in maven build. My pom.xml is:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <testExcludes>
                    <exclude>**/Test1.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/Test2.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/Test3.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/Test4.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/Test5.java</exclude>
                </testExcludes>
            </configuration> 
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>                  
    </executions>
```

```
enter code here
```

But When I'm trying to run my Test classes that is excluded from build, is giving ClassNotFoundException.

Kindly, guide me..

Comment: You configure the compiler-plugin to exclude some of your Test-classes from compilation (not from packaging!). And then you wonder why you can't run those tests? What am I missing? Or what are you actually trying to achieve?
Classes under src/test are usually not packaged anyway but if you want to modify the packaging behaviour you would have to configure the jar-plugin, not the compiler-plugin.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your kind suggestion. I want to compile the test classes that is in src/test/java, but i want that to exclude from war file.

Comment: 1) The tests should be compiled automatically if you do not configure the compiler plugin like above.
2) The test classes won't be included in the WAR unless you explicitly configure this in your pom.xml. So the default behaviour of maven should do exactly what you need!
BTW: the maven way is to have all your classes in a separate JAR module and make your WAR depend on this JAR.

Comment: Thanks everyone.. I fixed it with your kind support..

Comment: It would be really nice if you guys actually posted those answers as answers, not comments.

Answer (score -1):

I have added below plugins so now its skipping the test cases:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: why did you removed the test cases from packaging phase where you already spent time developing them ??!!